# NDIS6 LWF installation problems via DPInst and DIFxAPI

Tags: filter, ndis

We have a NDIS6 LWF driver which installs fine if installed from the adapter's property sheet, but does not install neither via DPInst, nor via DriverPackageInstall function from DIFxAPI.dll

Apart from vendor info and descriptions, it differs from the NDIS6 LWF Passthru sample in the following ways:

1. binds only to WLAN medium:
   HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes,,"wlan"
2. specifies DriverPackageType=Network (a requirement of DIFxAPI)
3. passthru sample says "compression" here, we say "custom"
   HKR, Ndi,FilterClass,, custom

The current full version of the INF is stored at https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By4TPkL7aR-RelRSZC1PZmdQYnc/edit?pli=1 because it's too big to quote it here.

So, the question is: what else does this INF require in order to be installed via DIFxAPI? (It currently installs fine via the adapter's property sheet)

Comment: Can you inject the driver with "pnputil -a"?  If the GUI works, then the INF itself is probably fine.  I'd guess it's a problem with the way you're calling the DIFxAPI function.  Can you post the function call?  I don't know much about DIFxAPI or DPInst, so I can't be too useful, but maybe somebody else can.

Comment: the difxapi call is as follows:
        rc := DriverPackageInstall(
          PWideChar(cSrcInf),
          0,
          nil,
          NeedReboot
        );
        if rc <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
        begin
          RaiseErr(rc);
        end;
        Application.MessageBox('DriverPackageInstall returned SUCCESS!', 'Information');

and we are getting: error code 0x0000000D - the result of RaiseErr(rc) invocation meaning that DriverPackageInstall returned 0x0000000D

Comment: sorry, but StackOverflow appears to not support code formatting in comments... :(

Comment: FormatMessageW(0x0D) returns "The data is invalid."

Comment: tried pnputil -a, seems to work both on win7 and win81.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update NetCfgInstanceId in inf file and have same id as UniqueName in registration attributes at driver entry.

You can use following site to have a new id generated and replace your present:

www.uuidgen.com